# How to fix Spring Cloud Kafka Binder WARN from IndicativeQueryService "Store (store) could not be found in Streams context"?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams dependency in the project. The service is communicating with other services using Kafka, these are listeners set up in `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        kafka:
            stream:
                bindings:
                    listenToBookTopic-in-0:
                        consumer:
                            applicationId: someAppId
                    listenToUserTopic-in-0:
                        consumer:
                            applicationId: someAppId2
                            materializedAs: user-store
                    listenToRolesTopic-in-0:
                        consumer:
                            applicationId: someAppId3
                            materializedAs: role-store
```

Among others there is a Kafka listener for the Book objects:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, OldBook>, KStream<String, NewBook>> listenToTopic() {
    return stream -> stream
            .map((key, oldBook) -> {
                try {
                    final var newBook = bookService.processBook(oldBook);
                    final String newKey = createNewKey(newBook);
                    return KeyValue.pair(newKey, newBook);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                    return KeyValue.pair("", null);
                }
            });
}
```

Book Service:

```
@Autowired
private final StateStoreService stateStoreService;

public NewBook processBook(OldBook oldBook) {
    final var newBook = createBook(oldBook);
    newBook.setUser(stateStoreService.getUserById(oldBook.getId());
    newBook.setRoles(stateStoreService.getRolesById(oldBook.getId());
    return newBook;
}
```

StateStoreService:

```
@Autowired
private final InteractiveQueryService indicativeQueryService;

public Optional<User> getUserById(final String id) {
    final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, User> userStore = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(
            properties.getUserStore(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
    return Optional.ofNullable(userStore.get(brid));
}

public Optional<Role> getRoleById(final String id) {
    final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Role> store = interactiveQueryService
        .getQueryableStore(properties.getRoleStore(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
    return Optional.ofNullable(store.get(id));
}
```

**So, what happens is:**
when the `StateStoreService.getUserById()` is called from the normal request scope, then `InteractiveQueryService.getQueryableStore()` throws no WARNs. When the same methods of `StateStoreService` are invoked from the `listenToBookTopic` bean, the WARN containing following is produced:

```
"Store storeName could not be found in Streams context, falling back to all known Streams instances"
```

According to my investigations, when `getUserById()` is invoked from the listenToBookTopic bean, some contextSpecificKafkaStreams are found at the line

```
KafkaStreams contextSpecificKafkaStreams = getThreadContextSpecificKafkaStreams();
```

This leads to the check if the contextSpecificKafkaStreams contains required StateStore. Obviously it doesnt, so Spring falls back to looking into all other available KafkaStreams. I assume that the reason for such context-specific StateStores being created are materialized views assigned to the specific listener running on the separate thread with specific name, by which its distinguished if the StateStore is context-specific for this given thread.

**Actual problem** is that the WARN is produced for each Book received. I was searching for some possible solutions, but have found nothing relevant. Is it possible to get rid of this warning in some clean and gentle way?

Comment: See the source code, it seems to be related to threads: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/InteractiveQueryService.java